# No module named 'discord.ext'; 'discord' is not a package

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, chatgpt-api

I am working on a discord bot in python and just trying to do the basics.

I am using this code to start it up:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
print("running")
client =commands.Bot(command_prefix = "c!")

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
   await ctx.send("hello")
  
client.run(token)
```

but i keep getting this annoying error:

```
from discord.ext import commands
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.ext'; 'discord' is not a package
```

I am not sure why this is happenign

I have tried installing discord.py again and rechanging the name but nothing has worked! Pleasehelp!

Answer (score 1):

```bash
pip uninstall discord
pip install discord.py
```

You have likely installed `discord` package instead of `discord.py`

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).